# Visual Studio 2015 Community Interop.OSVersionHelper Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When opening VS 2015 Community, I seem to always get an error:

[image: error message]

This has been a continuous headache for me, and there's no other documented errors found on forums, etc...

I've tried `repairing` my VS 2015 and that still didn't fix the issue, I've been trying to fix it for 2 days and have only really tried repairing it, does anyone know what this error means? And is it fixable?

I now after this tried to open another app - `Xamarin Studio` and I am greeted with a lovely message with a similar message, screenshot:

[image: second error]

[Pastebin with all error information](http://pastebin.com/17XrG1Y7)

On [this](https://feedback.bistudio.com/T120135) forum thread, I'm getting the similar issue and I had recently reinstalled my .NET framework, so I will try upgrading it, will get back to you guys.

Fixed! ... Upgraded to 4.6.2 and it worked.

I'm not gonna delete the post as I think it can really help people cause it took me a long time to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: *'m not gonna delete the post* you shouldn't, but just post your solution as an answer and then accept it yourself. And maybe get rid of the 'fuck life' as well :]

Comment: Pffft thanks @stijn, forgot I could do that :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update to the newest .NET version and repair if already there.